# Conversion of protons into neutrons in stable nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics

Can proton convert into neutron and another neutron simultaneously into proton in nucleus of a stable element? Which conditions are needed for this? Is this question make sense at current stage of science and technology?

Comment: That is the dominant low energy approximate nuclear interaction that causes the nuclei to stay together.

Comment: Are you familiar with isospin? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177482/123208

Comment: have a look  at a recent  work that reviews in the introduction  the binding into nuclei . https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=85787